# UI test automation of Silverlight Navigation Applications

Tags: silverlight, automation

I am writing Silverlight UI test automation using this article as a guide: http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2009/01/26/unit-testing-in-silverlight-part-4-the-ui.aspx

It works for small Silverlight applications, but when I try to add to TestPanel a Silverlight Navigation Application, I get this exception:
"Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key LayoutRootGridStyle [Line: 10 Position: 37]". Here's the code:

```
[TestClass]
public class Tests : SilverlightTest
{
    private MainPage _myControl;

    [TestMethod]
    [Asynchronous]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        _myControl = new MainPage(); // <-- exception
        TestPanel.Children.Add(_myControl);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to include the resources from the Navigation project in your test project or it can't find the correct styles, LayoutRootGridStyle for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `MainPage` inherited from `Page`?  If so, I think that TestPanel would need to define a `Grid` with the name "LayoutRoot".

Check out this link for another view of the same issue:
http://silverlight.codeplex.com/workitem/8175